# Outdoor patio heater stops working after use

Tags: heating

I bought one of those 8 foot patio heaters that use a 20 gallon propane tank to replace my old one.

It will run fine for a couple of hours on a full tank and then behave like it is running out of gas. Until eventually not being able to heat at all. If I leave it off for an hour and start it back up then it runs better and can heat. If I leave it until the next night then it runs 100% until degrading slowly again.

This sounds like it is directly related to the components heating up.

My old one that I used for many years never exhibited this problem so I think I can rule out my tanks and environment.

My guess is that some metal parts in the new heater are not made of the same metal parts as in the old heater. That the metal is inferior for the task and is expanding more under heat and restricting gas flow. But that is just my wild uninformed guess.

It was suggested that I return it but how am I going to prove it's not behaving properly and if its a problem with the design getting a replacement won't help.

I am thinking of changing the regulator with the one from my old unit next.

Comment: I have an older propane cook stove in one of my off-grid cabins, but it also has the capability to use natural gas if needed. However, there are two vents that need to be closed in propane use, but slightly open when using natural gas. Perhaps your device is similar, and you've got it in natural gas mode?

Note that I've never used it in natural gas mode before so I am unsure if that would cause the symptoms you're experiencing.

Comment: It may be freezing at the valve   I have a 400k btu  propane heater that runs on 100lb tank it draws so much propane through the line that it ices  up until the flow is restricted to nothing.

Comment: https://www.powerblanket.com/blog/how-can-i-prevent-my-propane-tank-from-freezing/.

Comment: Rather than icing, the liquid propane may be cooling so much as it boils into gas that it won't boil anymore, leaving you with no gas left. I'll guess that the colder the weather, the quicker this happens; does it?

Comment: @DanielGriscom  freezing occurs when demand for vapor exceeds liquid to vapor conversion that is the boiling process you refer to right?    In my case the demand of a 400k heater  required a 300 lb tank or larger(or a manifold that drew from 3 100 lb tanks simultaneously ). I suspect the 0P has a similar problem and may need a tank warmer or a bigger tank .  I was forced to go back to kerosene/diesel fueled heaters for portability reasons.

Comment: Robert tell us the btu rating on the new patio heater.

Comment: @Kris Propane [won't actually become solid at any pressure until it's close to -200°C](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/propane-d_1423.html). But, as it cools to and past 0°C, its vapor pressure gets lower and lower, until there's not enough to push the gas out of the tank. No freezing involved.

Comment: @Kris its 46,000 BTU. A lot of what people have said here makes sense. The idea about using a heating blanket is a novel one.But what I cannot understand is why the older heater never had this problem given the same conditions and same tank? Could a higher or lower BTU be the cause? I seem the recall the old heater getting a lot hotter. It sounded like an afterburner. The new one is much quieter.